# framework for communicating between apache web page and mono application

Tags: c#, .net, apache, mono, castle-monorail

I am working on an embedded project which involves hosting a web page as the main user interface for the headless system. This web page should basically look like a router web page with configurable settings. I plan to host this web page using the available Apache web server in the system.

However, the main application on the embedded system runs on Mono.

I would like to communicate between the web page and the Mono application.

Which framework would give me a good feature set to do this? I was thinking about PHP but I am not sure.

Please advice.

Thanks in advance,

Subbu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use Apache as a front-server that will forward requests to an embedded server in your service's process. There are a few options for hosting http apps in Mono processes. One of the more complete ones would probably be Manos de Mono (http://manosdemono.org/) .

see an example for a super-simple Manos web app here: https://gist.github.com/1065936